# how to use expath and Xquery to fetch a CSV file?

Tags: xml, csv, xpath, xquery, basex

How can this [example](https://gist.github.com/joewiz/2072e9f04838188b2aa6ee4ae0f72a15) of [expath](http://expath.org/modules/http-client/samples) be adapted to grab **and store** a CSV file directly from a website?

```
xquery version "3.1";

import module namespace hc = "http://expath.org/ns/http-client";

let $url := "https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Genesis-Chapter-1_Original-1611-KJV/"
let $request := 
    <hc:request href="{$url}" method="GET">
        <hc:header name="Connection" value="close"/>    
    </hc:request>
return
    hc:send-request($request)
```

Browsing to:

http://www.bccdc.ca/health-info/diseases-conditions/covid-19/data

the specific CSV file is:

http://www.bccdc.ca/Health-Info-Site/Documents/BCCDC_COVID19_Dashboard_Case_Details.csv

Of course, there are a multitude of ways to grab that file.  But, how would it be done with xquery as above?

Obviously, changing the URL is the starting point, which, indeed, results in a large CSV file printed to the console.

Comment: BaseX allows you to do `csv:doc('http://www.bccdc.ca/Health-Info-Site/Documents/BCCDC_COVID19_Dashboard_Case_Details.csv')`, for instance, without the complications of using EXPath and a HTTP request/response mode. The CSV module is documented at https://docs.basex.org/wiki/CSV_Module. If you wanted the plain text then there is `unparsed-text('http://www.bccdc.ca/Health-Info-Site/Documents/BCCDC_COVID19_Dashboard_Case_Details.csv')`

Comment: syntax or other error:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/65325993/4531180  with `csv:doc` .  does the namespace need to be imported, @MartinHonnen ?

Comment: I can run the query `csv:doc('http://www.bccdc.ca/Health-Info-Site/Documents/BCCDC_COVID19_Dashboard_Case_Details.csv')` in BaseX 9.4 GUI without importing the module or namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MartinHonnen already pointed out, BaseX has a CSV module.

Here is how to use it.

**csv file addressbook.csv**

```
FName, LName, Address, City
John, Doe, 3851 SW 52nd St., Miami
Mary, Dowson, 770 SE 21nd St., Orlando
```

**XQuery**

```
let $text := file:read-text("c:\Users\Yitzhak\Downloads\addressbook.csv")
return csv:parse($text, map { 'header': true() })
```

**Output**

```
<csv>
  <record>
    <FName>John</FName>
    <LName> Doe</LName>
    <Address> 3851 SW 52nd St.</Address>
    <City> Miami</City>
  </record>
  <record>
    <FName>Mary</FName>
    <LName> Dowson</LName>
    <Address> 770 SE 21nd St.</Address>
    <City> Orlando</City>
  </record>
</csv>
```