# BaseX error: No namespace declared for 'doc:csv'

Tags: xml, csv, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces, basex

[Referencing](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/CSV_Module) the csv module, how is the following data downloaded?

```
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor/covid$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor/covid$ basex uri.xq 
Stopped at /home/nicholas/flwor/covid/uri.xq, 3/13:
[XPST0081] No namespace declared for 'doc:csv'.
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor/covid$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor/covid$ cat uri.xq 
xquery version "3.1";

let $csv := doc:csv('http://www.bccdc.ca/Health-Info-Site/Documents/BCCDC_COVID19_Dashboard_Lab_Information.csv') as $data
return $data
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor/covid$
```

which of the following:

csv:parse
csv:serialize
csv:doc

is best used to grab this data?

and is there a missing import statement for the namespace?

---

with powershell:

[how to get the column headers for CSV data with Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65304231/4531180)

Comment: I think instead of `doc:csv' you rather want `csv:doc`.

Comment: correct; I'll try that.  thx.